# How to download scikit-learn in Pycharm? Command errored out with exit status 1:

Tags: installation, scikit-learn, scipy, pip, pycharm

I am trying to download scikit-learn in my PyCharm project and keep getting '''Command errored out with exit status 1:'''

I already have numpy and scipy installed. When i attempt to install through the interpreter I receive this error. My pip is upgraded to the latest version. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4UQ1.jpg)

When I attempt to install scikit-learn through the command line, I receive this ...

```
pip install -U  numpy scipy scikit-learn
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.19.4)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.5.4)
Collecting scikit-learn
Using cached scikit-learn-0.23.2.tar.gz (7.2 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/bin/python 
/Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip install --ignore- 
installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/gb/cxz768tj4hd0wvc43c1s0qhc0000gn/T/pip- 
build-env-wt9927_r/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: 
-i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.28.5' 'numpy==1.13.3; 
python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and 
platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.0; 
python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and 
platform_python_implementation != '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; 
python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; 
python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; 
python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; 
python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; 
python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'scipy>=0.19.1'
   cwd: None
 Complete output (277 lines):
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX" and 
platform_python_implementation == "CPython"' don't match your environment
Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX" and 
 platform_python_implementation != "CPython"' don't match your environment
Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match 
 your environment
Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match 
your environment
 Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match 
your environment
 Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.8" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match 
your environment
 Collecting numpy==1.17.3
Using cached numpy-1.17.3.zip (6.4 MB)
Collecting Cython>=0.28.5
 Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)
Collecting scipy>=0.19.1
Using cached scipy-1.5.4-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (29.1 MB)
Collecting wheel
Using cached wheel-0.36.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Collecting setuptools
Using cached setuptools-51.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for numpy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: numpy, wheel, setuptools, scipy, Cython
  Running setup.py install for numpy: started
  Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, 
 tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/gb/cxz768tj4hd0wvc43c1s0qhc0000gn/T/pip- 
 install-gi_o_78r/numpy_ab276f9e47f3407ba386404cf7c898c7/setup.py'"'"'; 
 __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/gb/cxz768tj4hd0wvc43c1s0qhc0000gn/T/pip-install- 
gi_o_78r/numpy_ab276f9e47f3407ba386404cf7c898c7/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, 
'"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', 
'"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 
/private/var/folders/gb/cxz768tj4hd0wvc43c1s0qhc0000gn/T/pip-record-n0sq1cv7/install- 
record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 
/private/var/folders/gb/cxz768tj4hd0wvc43c1s0qhc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-wt9927_r/overlay -- 
  compile --install-headers /private/var/folders/gb/cxz768tj4hd0wvc43c1s0qhc0000gn/T/pip- 
 build- 
env-wt9927_r/overlay/include/site/python3.9/numpy
       cwd: /private/var/folders/gb/cxz768tj4hd0wvc43c1s0qhc0000gn/T/pip-install- 
  gi_o_78r/numpy_ab276f9e47f3407ba386404cf7c898c7/
  Complete output (251 lines):
  Running from numpy source directory.

  Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
  with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

    - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                             release)
    - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)


  blas_opt_info:
  blas_mkl_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/lib', 
'/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  blis_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries blis not found in ['/Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/lib', 
'/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries openblas not found in ['/Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/lib', 
'/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries tatlas not found in ['/Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/lib', 
'/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_blas_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries satlas not found in ['/Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/lib', 
'/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_blas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  customize UnixCCompiler
     libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in 
['/Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_blas_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in 
['/Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  accelerate_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries accelerate not found in ['/Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/lib', 
'/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
  Library accelerate was not found. Ignoring
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries veclib not found in ['/Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/lib', 
'/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
  Library veclib was not found. Ignoring
    FOUND:
      extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '- 
I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
      extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
      define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]

    FOUND:
      extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '- 
I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
      extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
      define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]

  xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting 
 install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools.
  non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
  lapack_opt_info:
  lapack_mkl_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/lib', 
'/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_lapack_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries openblas not found in ['/Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/lib', 
'/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_clapack_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/lib', 
 '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  flame_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries flame not found in ['/Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/lib', 
'/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in /Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in 
/Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

    FOUND:
      extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '- 
I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
      extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
      define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]

  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py:274: 
UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running install
  running build
  running config_cc
  unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
  running config_fc
  unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
  running build_src
  build_src
  building py_modules sources
  creating build
  creating build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9
  creating build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy
  creating build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/numpy/distutils
  building library "npymath" sources
  get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu95', 'nag', 'absoft', 'ibm', 'intel', 'gnu', 
'g95', 'pg']'
  customize Gnu95FCompiler
  Could not locate executable gfortran
  Could not locate executable f95
  customize NAGFCompiler
  customize AbsoftFCompiler
  Could not locate executable f90
  Could not locate executable f77
  customize IBMFCompiler
  Could not locate executable xlf90
  Could not locate executable xlf
  customize IntelFCompiler
  Could not locate executable ifort
  Could not locate executable ifc
  customize GnuFCompiler
  Could not locate executable g77
  customize G95FCompiler
  Could not locate executable g95
  customize PGroupFCompiler
  Could not locate executable pgfortran
  don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
  C compiler: gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic 
-DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g

  compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core - 
Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath - 
Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/include - 
I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c'
  gcc: _configtest.c
  xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting 
 install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools.
  failure.
  removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/private/var/folders/gb/cxz768tj4hd0wvc43c1s0qhc0000gn/T/pip-install- 
gi_o_78r/numpy_ab276f9e47f3407ba386404cf7c898c7/setup.py", line 443, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "/private/var/folders/gb/cxz768tj4hd0wvc43c1s0qhc0000gn/T/pip-install- 
gi_o_78r/numpy_ab276f9e47f3407ba386404cf7c898c7/setup.py", line 435, in setup_package
      setup(**metadata)
    File "/private/var/folders/gb/cxz768tj4hd0wvc43c1s0qhc0000gn/T/pip-install- 
gi_o_78r/numpy_ab276f9e47f3407ba386404cf7c898c7/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 171, in setup
      return old_setup(**new_attr)
    File "/Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File 
 "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/core.py", line 
 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File 
  "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 
 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File 
 "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 
  985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/private/var/folders/gb/cxz768tj4hd0wvc43c1s0qhc0000gn/T/pip-install- 
  gi_o_78r/numpy_ab276f9e47f3407ba386404cf7c898c7/numpy/distutils/command/install.py", line 
 62, in run
      r = self.setuptools_run()
    File "/private/var/folders/gb/cxz768tj4hd0wvc43c1s0qhc0000gn/T/pip-install- 
 gi_o_78r/numpy_ab276f9e47f3407ba386404cf7c898c7/numpy/distutils/command/install.py", line 
 36, in setuptools_run
      return distutils_install.run(self)
    File 






"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/
install.py", 
 line 546, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py", 
 line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File 
   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 
  985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/private/var/folders/gb/cxz768tj4hd0wvc43c1s0qhc0000gn/T/pip-install- 
  gi_o_78r/numpy_ab276f9e47f3407ba386404cf7c898c7/numpy/distutils/command/build.py", line 
 47, in run
      old_build.run(self)
    File 
 "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/command/
 build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py", 
 line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File 
 "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 
 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/private/var/folders/gb/cxz768tj4hd0wvc43c1s0qhc0000gn/T/pip-install- 
  gi_o_78r/numpy_ab276f9e47f3407ba386404cf7c898c7/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", 
  line 142, in run
      self.build_sources()
    File "/private/var/folders/gb/cxz768tj4hd0wvc43c1s0qhc0000gn/T/pip-install- 
 gi_o_78r/numpy_ab276f9e47f3407ba386404cf7c898c7/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 
 153, in build_sources
      self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
    File "/private/var/folders/gb/cxz768tj4hd0wvc43c1s0qhc0000gn/T/pip-install- 
  gi_o_78r/numpy_ab276f9e47f3407ba386404cf7c898c7/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", 
 line 286, in build_library_sources
      sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
    File "/private/var/folders/gb/cxz768tj4hd0wvc43c1s0qhc0000gn/T/pip-install- 
 gi_o_78r/numpy_ab276f9e47f3407ba386404cf7c898c7/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 
 369, in generate_sources
      source = func(extension, build_dir)
    File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 669, in get_mathlib_info
      raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
  RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 
 /Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; 
sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/gb/cxz768tj4hd0wvc43c1s0qhc0000gn/T/pip-install- 
gi_o_78r/numpy_ab276f9e47f3407ba386404cf7c898c7/setup.py'"'"'; 
__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/gb/cxz768tj4hd0wvc43c1s0qhc0000gn/T/pip-install- 
gi_o_78r/numpy_ab276f9e47f3407ba386404cf7c898c7/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, 
'"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', 
'"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 
 /private/var/folders/gb/cxz768tj4hd0wvc43c1s0qhc0000gn/T/pip-record-n0sq1cv7/install- 
record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 
 /private/var/folders/gb/cxz768tj4hd0wvc43c1s0qhc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-wt9927_r/overlay -- 
compile --install-headers /private/var/folders/gb/cxz768tj4hd0wvc43c1s0qhc0000gn/T/pip- 
 build-env-wt9927_r/overlay/include/site/python3.9/numpy Check the logs for full command 
 output.
```

---

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 
 /Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/bin/python 
 /Users/dannydibeneditto/pythonProject2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip install --ignore- 
 installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/gb/cxz768tj4hd0wvc43c1s0qhc0000gn/T/pip- 
 build-env-wt9927_r/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary 
 :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.28.5' 'numpy==1.13.3; 
  python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and 
 platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.0; 
 python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and 
 platform_python_implementation != '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; 
 python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; 
 python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; 
   python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; 
  python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; 
  python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'scipy>=0.19.1' Check 
 the logs 
    for full command output.
```

Comment: You're on Mac? Have you installed Xcode?

Comment: Yes, I am on a Mac. No, I have not stalled Xcode. Do i need to?

Comment: That was the problem, thank you!